# In backdraftjs can you trigger a component re-render from within the component?

Tags: javascript, backdraftjs

Here is a backdraftjs component that does not work:

```
class ClickButton extends Component {
    constructor(kwargs) {
        super(kwargs);
        this.clicked = false;
    }
    
    toggleButton() {
        this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    }
    
    bdElements() {
        return e.div(
            {
                className: this.clicked ? 'clicked' : '',
                bdAdvise: {click: 'toggleButton'}
            },
            'Click Me'
        );
    }
}
```

...that is, the component doesn't re-render with the "clicked" class after you click it (and of course it doesn't).

I could change it to use watchables, and then trigger the change from outside:

```
class ClickButton extends Component.withWatchables('isClicked') {    
    bdElements() {
        return e.div(
            {
                bdReflect: {
                    className: ['isClicked', c => c ? 'clicked' : '']
                },
                bdAdvise: {click: this.kwargs.toggleClick}
            },
            'Click Me'
        );
    }
}
```

But is there some way to keep this all internal to the component? Something like ReactJS component state, where you make a change and it causes the component to re-render and reflect the new state?

Comment: OK the thing I didn't understand is that you can manipulate a watchable within a component simply using "this.[watchableName]". So in react terms, a watchable does double duty as BOTH the passed-in prop (which you can manipulate from outside the component) AND as an internal state variable. That is pretty cool actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning at the end with the key question:

> But is there some way to keep this all internal to the component?
> Something like ReactJS component state, where you make a change and it
> causes the component to re-render and reflect the new state?

A ReactJS component state is an *aggregate* state: it almost-always  controls multiple facets of a component (always, with non-trivial components). And mutating one of those facets implies mutating the aggregate state object, which in turn causes a "re-render" of the entire component. You can certainly construct backdraft components to follow this model, but backdraft was not designed to follow such a model (for rational engineering objectives discussed in other forums).

Turning now to the op's particular example, notice that the first solution exposes the property `clicked` on the public interface of instances of `ClickButton`. So, clearly, this example does not "keep this all internal to the component".

I think the real question is, "what is the public interface that `ClickButton` is offering?" I'm guessing op wants:

1. a button
2. that has a public read/write boolean property `clicked`
3. that toggles its `clicked` property each time the button is clicked
4. that sets its DOM class to 'clicked' when the `clicked` property changes from false to true and conversely

Here is such a component:

```
class ClickButton extends Component.withWatchables('clicked') {
    bdElements() {
        return e.button(
            {
                bdReflectClass: ['clicked', value=>(value ? 'clicked' : '')],
                bdAdvise_click: e=>(this.clicked = !this.clicked)
            },
            'Click Me'
        );
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the above code, live in a pen: https://codepen.io/rcgill/pen/eYvrNeB

Perhaps I've failed to understand the thrust of the question and the op is looking for ways to either implement (1) private data, or (2) state mutation implies *complete* re-render. There are canonical solutions to the former; you can do the latter with backdraft, but if that's the model you prefer, it's probably better to use ReactJS.

Comment: BTW just want to note -- `bdReflectClass` is just a shortcut for `bdReflect: {className: [expression]}` -- so you can use this to bdReflect into any writeable DOM attribute: innerHTML, className, whatever.

Comment: `bdReflectClass !== bdReflect` since `bdReflectClass: {watchable: [<args>]}` mutates only a part of the className whereas `bdRelfect:{className: [<args>]}` mutates the entire className (assuming no staticClassName). See https://backdraftjs.org/docs.html#bd-core.post-processing-functions.bdReflect compared to https://backdraftjs.org/docs.html#bd-core.post-processing-functions.bdReflectClass and